# Uploaded assets not saving in specified local folder

Tags: assets

I have a local asset folder defined with name 'Local storage' file system path `../public/cms/images/`, and URL `/cms/images/`.

I create an Assets field named 'Hero image', not restricted to a single folder, with source 'Local storage', and default upload location 'Local storage' with path `heroes/{slug}/`.

I'd expect uploads for Hero image to land in the `/public/cms/images/heroes/{slug}` folder. When I do upload an asset, this folder is created, yet the asset lands in the root `/public/cms/images` folder.

Why might this be?

Comment: Try using absolute paths/URLs and see if that works. You probably just have a relative path setup incorrectly somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer really belongs to Brad, as he mentioned it to me. But he doesn't really need the points, does he ;)

What you want in that slot is {owner.slug}, and then the proper sub-path will ensue.

The explanation is deep in the doc page at: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields

To wit,

> "Note that if you are creating the Assets field within a Matrix field,
>   the source element is going to be the actual Matrix block, not the
>   element that the Matrix field is being created on. So if your Matrix
>   field is attached to an entry, and you want to output the entry ID in
>   your dynamic subfolder path, you would type {owner.id} not just {id}."

Comment: You get the rep fair and square. :) Didn't even think it might be in a Matrix field.

Comment: I did rather make the assumption, didn't I...but the reason is that the only place {slug} is mentioned in this fashion is in the form for Matrix images. Really, it should say {owner.slug} there to be correct, shouldn't it?

Comment: That's a good point for matrix fields. However I'm still having the same problem for non-matrix fields after making the file system path absolute.

Comment: The correct subfolder is created in the filesystem, but as the root 'Local storage' location is highlighted when I open the 'Add an asset' dialog it adds it there.  If I highlight the correct folder manually I get an error where there is a double directory separator slash: 'Error uploading the file: The folder "/home/apps/test/public/cms/images/heroes//history/" does not exist.'  I've double checked and there don't seem to be any trailing slashes on the paths I've set.

Comment: Ah, I understand now that this default upload location will only be used if the asset is dragged onto the field, or the 'Restrict uploads to a single folder?' is checked. I'm still getting the double slash error though.

Comment: Hmm. I actually have a trailing slash on both my Asset file system path and web url. If I use {slug} in an ordinary Assets field and drag-drop an image, things work as expected, no double slash error, and the image ends up in the directory associated with the page slug. This also works if I take the trailing slash off. Maybe try this with devMode true in general.php, then send a support request from the CP with logs included as should be automatic, so Brad can look at your circumstance?

Comment: Another little interesting point is that the Assets dialog actually put the trailing slash back into the file system path when I saved it. So I wonder what version of Craft you are running? Latest 2.2.2601 here.

Comment: I'm running 2.2.2601. This was a permissions issue of being unable to create the folder rather than a problem with the double slashes. Many thanks for your help on this.

Comment: There you go, and most welcome, Alex.